# Navigational Properties vs Inheritance Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, oop

I am trying to explore if there are different ways than how I am used to using EntityFramework and relationships between data models.

Let's say, I have the following two classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string JobDescripion { get; set; }
}
```

Let's assume there is a **One to Many** relationship between these two models in the database, with the many on the `Employee` class.

I would map this as follow:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    //Navigational Property
    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string JobDescripion { get; set; }

    //navigational property 
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

This for me, takes away the principle of Object Orientated, as the `Employee` now do not Inherit from the `Person` class anymore, or at least, from my understanding.

Is this proper design, and would still be considered good Object Orientated Code, or is there a better way to be handling this, if for instance, I would like the following inheritance in my code:

```
public class Employee : Person
```

How would EntityFramework handle this?

Comment: Inheritance represents an **"is a"** relationship, while composition (navigational properties) an **"has a"** relationship. Before continue identify what kind of relationship there is between `Employee` and `Person`.

Comment: @FredericoDipuma a Person can have multiple Employees. One to many relationship

Comment: If this models your domain (a person **has** employees, but **is NOT** an employee) then you are done. Use navigational properties.

Comment: @monstertjie_za - why make the distinctions between "Person" and "Employee"? Since all employees *are* Persons, do you even need the "Person" class at all? You can make a self-referencing FK in the database so that Employees can have other Employees (like a manager and the people who report to them, etc) and EF can handle that.

Comment: @StephenByrne Let's say I was to introduce another object to the code, called Client.  Client and Employee would have overlapping properties, which is currently sitting in the Person class.  With you approach, there would be duplicating properties between Client and Employee?

Comment: @monstertjie_za - that's a fair point, but I'd argue that these two things are different Domain concepts; and introducing a base "Person" class just to save some duplicated properties is making things more complex than they need to be. And what if the Client is a company, not an individual?

Comment: If with "one-to-many" you mean that `Person` is a base class that can have many subclasses, then this is not the right wording and "Inheritance" is the only correct term. Since it seems a bit weird for a "person" to have employees, I think what you mean is inheritance: an `Employee` *is-a* `Person`, a `Client` *is-a* `Person`.